# How to split modules in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am just starting with vue.js and cannot work out how to split the code into separate files. I am using Visual Studio Code, and have copied a basic 'hello world' example from vuejs.org, which works fine:

```
<script type="module">
import { createApp, ref } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'

createApp({
  setup() {

    const message = ref('Hello World!')

    return {
      message
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
```

but I will want to add a lot of javascript so wish to split my code into files. I have followed the example for splitting modules on vuejs.org and have tried the following html/js, but when I run the code in a browser I get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Property "message" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.   at

So what am I missing? I have found some posts mentioning this error but they all relate to much more complex scenarios than my simple 'hello world'!

```
<script type="module">
   import { createApp, ref } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'
   import MySetup from './setup.js'

  createApp(MySetup).mount('#app')
</script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
```

and setup.js:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const message = ref('Hello World!')

    return {
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Normally you need to import `ref` from vue inside your `setup.js` file

Comment: Thanks, there was an error, see edited post. I tried importing {ref} to the js as well.

Comment: so does your code work now?

Comment: Not that example, no, but now working with SFC construct, which I find suits me better.